# Routing problem when using some routing model inside primary routing

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have a problem with routing in exist project. I'm adding new page, everythin going well only routing didn't work well.

I have this primary routing:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'home',
    pathMatch: 'full',
  },
    {
    path: 'home',
    component: InformationPageComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'view-model',
    loadChildren: './view-model/model-20-sm.module#Model20SmModule',
    canActivateChild: []
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    component: PageNotFoundComponent
  }
];
```

and model-routing.ts as:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {
        path: 'view-model',
        data: {
          title: 'LABEL.DELEGHE',
        },
        children: [
          {
            path: 'dettaglio-ditta',
            data: {
              title: 'LABEL.RICERCA_PAT',
              breadcrumb: 'LABEL.RICERCA_PAT',
            },
            children: [
              {
                path: 'dettaglio-quadro',
                data: {
                  title: 'LABEL.DETTAGLIO_MODELLO_20SM',
                  breadcrumb: 'LABEL.DETTAGLIO_MODELLO_20SM',
                },
                component: DettaglioQuadroComponent
              },
              {
                path: '',
                data: {
                  title: 'LABEL.RICERCA_PAT',
                  breadcrumb: '',
                },
                component: DettaglioDittaComponent,
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            path: '',
            component: DelegheComponent,
          },
        ]
      },

    ])
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

Now working,

- when starting project opening http://localhost:4200/#/home
  in breadcrumb shows only `Home >`
- when click in `view-model` on menu , going correct in view-model page, but in breadcrumb didn't show `Home > view-model` , show only `Home >`
  Also in URL show only `http://localhost:4200/#/view-model`
  I want to show `http://localhost:4200/#/home/view-model`

Can you suggest me any idea how to fix it please?

Comment: the `view-model` has the same path as your redirect. you should give it a different path name

Comment: The same path ? Sorry, in wich part, I didn't understand

Comment: They both use: `path: ''`

Comment: I changed it, but the problem exist again

Comment: The path you created is /view-model/view-model with this setup. You can empty the path in your lazy module route at the top level

Comment: Can you write code changed please?